# Visual C++: Hiding the Command Prompt in Windows Form Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, command-line, command-prompt

I'm having some trouble in a Visual C++ Windows Form application (I'm moderately new to the language itself, but I understand other languages well).  At various times, system() is used, and the command prompt pops up for a split second.  I would like to stop this of course. I searched around and found this:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>
```

Later, in main.

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Here is my Main function:

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    BoxBeta::BoxForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}
```

The system commands are called inside the events triggered by the changing of the text of a text box.  The error I am getting is LNK1120 unresolved externals, and it seems to directly coincide with the ShowWindow line.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Instead of trying to hide the command window, avoid creating it in the first place (e.g., using CreateProcess, ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx,  WinExec, or something built into .NET, since you're actually using C++/CLI or some such, not actual C++).

Comment: Process.Start() is probably the best way to tackle this instead of system().  There's an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx

Comment: Thank you; I ended up using ShellExecute, and it was exactly what I needed.